# How to access default jackson serialization in a custom serializer with the same object

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Copy here an old answer, that only worked to some people.
The question is,

1. Where should I locate the register part of the BeanSerializerModifier ?
2. what do I do with the ObjectMapper object ?

A BeanSerializerModifier will provide you access to the default serialization.

Inject a default serializer into the custom serializer

```
public class MyClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {
    private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer;

    public MyClassSerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer) {
        this.defaultSerializer = checkNotNull(defaultSerializer);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(MyClass myclass, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (myclass.getSomeProperty() == true) {
            provider.setAttribute("special", true);
        }
        defaultSerializer.serialize(myclass, gen, provider);
    }
}
```

Create a BeanSerializerModifier for MyClass

```
public class MyClassSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == MySpecificClass.class) {
            return new MyClassSerializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
        }
        return serializer;
    }
}
```

Register the serializer modifier

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                .setSerializerModifier(new MyClassSerializerModifier()));
```

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: yes, I'm using spring

Comment: Have you tried registering it as a `@Bean` in a class annotated with `@Configuration`? E.G. `@Bean public static ObjectMapper objectMapper() { return new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                .setSerializerModifier(new MyClassSerializerModifier())); }` ?